# Changed app name, now can't run it on device (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.)

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I've uploaded my app to the app store with a name long name, when i realised that you couldn't see the full name on my ipod touch homescreen i wanted to change it, so i've decided to change my whole project name too.
After that i changed the bundle display name to a shorter name i could see the whole name on my device. Now here's the problem. When i try to run it on the simulator, it works fine and the name changed BUT when i run it on my ipod i get this error:

```
A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
```

I've deleted the old app with the long name on my ipod but now, i can't even open the new one. I don't know if it has something to do with the manage scheme (since i had to use it to change the project name or what)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like, that your `Bundle Identifier` (e.g.: `com.Your-Company.Your-App`) changed after renaming your project. The `provisioning profile` is bound to this ID.
I recommend to never change the `Bundle Identifier`.
In order to change the App's name on the `Homescreen` i recommend to edit the value of the `Bundle Name` inside your `Info.plist`

Comment: And now what should i do to fix my problem...? Im pretty sure i changed the bundle name inside the info.plist... I think my problem is related to the manage scheme part...

Comment: In order to exclude the `Bundle Identifier` issue you should compare the `Bundle Identifier` from your project target settings, with the one in your `provisioning profile` (check in Apple-Dev's `Member Center` or in Xcode's `Organizer`). As the error still is, that a valid `provisioning profile` is still missing.